# Is there a tool like `cronolog` or `rotatelogs`, but also with compression and removal like in `logrotate`?

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate

I want simple piped logging without config files or system-wide rules for periodic command execution.

Are there any projects that allows to do that? Expecting something like this:

```
./my_program_that_generate_logs | cronologrotate /var/log/ololog/%Y_%M/%d.log --compress-after '30 days' --remove-after '1 year'
```

Comment: Why not stick with `logrotate` and write a little crontab that compresses after 30 days and deletes after a year? If you're interested in this I can post the relevant cron lines.

Comment: For example, to avoid accessing the system as `root` (or other user that edits crontab). Also using logrotate is having config files which I also sometimes try to avoid.